# What does "subject teacher" refer to?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

In my country, we have two main kinds of teacher (not counting university lecturers) – primary school teachers and secondary school teachers. The latter kind are referred to as 'subject teachers' (albeit in my own language, obviously), because they have always specialised in a specific subject or set of subjects (as opposed to primary school teachers, who have studied all the subjects taught in primary school). My question is: can I use *subject teacher* for this, or does that refer to something else in English? If it does, is there another word you'd suggest I use instead?

Thank you!

Comment: From a UK perspective, for me 'secondary school teacher' is explanatory enough, since I know that secondary teachers teach one (or a couple of) subject(s). It depends on the context of what you're writing/talking about. If there is sufficient context, I think 'subject teacher' *is* understandable, but my preference is simply 'secondary school teacher'.

Comment: I have not come across the phrase **subject teacher**. The obvious interpretation is that the person referred to teaches a subject (or possibly subjects). It might also be interpreted as a teacher who is subject to some authority. I can't think of a particular word that means the teacher of a single subject. To make it clear, you would need to spell it out.

Comment: @JMB and Ronald Sole Thank you – "secondary school teacher" it is then!

Comment: The exact phrasing "subject teacher" doesn't occur naturally in my dialect.  Without a clarifying context, I would find it confusing.  However, using the specific subject is natural and common: an English teacher, a science teacher, a math teacher, and so on.  More generally, a high school teacher is also a natural phrasing.  It might matter where your target audience lies, since my dialect is a variety of American English.

Comment: @Hannah - note that Americans will likely call these "high school teachers", a term also used here in Scotland. As far as educational terminology is concerned, there are differences even within the different countries of the UK, and in other English speaking countries.

Comment: The terms ["**subject teacher**" and "**class teacher**"](https://ask.gibbonedu.org/discussion/526/limitations-of-subject-teacher-vs-class-teacher) aren't particularly common among (British) Anglophones, but in any relevant context they should be easily understood.

Comment: I'd like to thank you all for input – since I can't notify more than one at a time, I'll have to do it like this (since writing a number of separate comments with roughly the same content makes no sense). You are right that there is quite a bit of cultural confusion here, but I guess "secondary school teacher" would work in any context, and – as some of you point out – "subject teacher" may work when it can be understood from the context.

Comment: I know the term (British English) but I suspect it's only used in schools where you have both. At my prep school we'd use 'subject teacher' to mean the ones who specialised, rather than teaching everything. e.g. "We have subject teachers for music, French, science, Art and PE. Everything else is taught by your form teacher." At senior school, every teacher was a subject specialist, so we didn't make the distinction.

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine Right – that makes sense! It's pretty much the same as in my language then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from the UK and I do not recognise the term "subject teacher".

There shouldn't be any need for you to use a term like this because our schooling works the same way you described - primary school teachers cover all subjects, and secondary school (also referred to as 'high school') teachers specialise in one subject.

If someone said "I'm a high school teacher" or "I'm a secondary school teacher", it would be assumed they specialise in a particular subject.

If you wanted to state the subject from the outset, you could say "I'm an English teacher", or "I'm a high school English teacher".

Comment: Thanks Astralbee! I think I'll just go with "secondary school teacher", since the use of "secondary school" seems to be more consistent than "high school", which seems to be more diverse in its use (for instance, in my country, many people think that "high school" refers specifically to a school that you attend between ages 12/13 and 15/16)

Comment: @Hannah "high school" is a throwback term. Some people still call them "junior" and "senior" schools, too.

Comment: Ehum... what does that mean? That it's a throwback term?